# Using Monte Carlo method in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-methods

I am working on the first version of the question written in the image below. I have generated a single random point using the `rand` command and tested whether or not that point was within the circle. Does my code accept the number of Monte Carlo functions as input value? I believe I have chosen `N`, the number of points to be small enough so I don't run out of memory. Also, when I run this code, it runs without any error but the graph does not show up. Looking for some help in places I might have went wrong.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

xinside = []
yinside = []
xoutside = []
youtside = []

insidecircle = 0
totalpoints = 10**3

for _ in range(totalpoints):
    x = random()
    y = random()
    if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
        insidecircle += 1
        xinside.append(x)
        yinside.append(y)
    else:
        xoutside.append(x)
        youtside.append(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(xinside, yinside, color='g', marker='s')
ax.scatter(xoutside, youtside, color='r', marker='s')
fig.show()
```

Comment: First things first, you are asked to create two functions - and you did not.

Comment: @DYZ yes I know but I am trying to solve the first function first, then work on the second

Comment: I didnt think i needed to solve the second function for the first to run correctly

Comment: You don't have the first one, either. You did not define _any_ functions in your program.

Comment: @DYZ yes you are right, i will try and work on that now. Thanks!

Comment: could you suggest how i could do that?

Comment: Hint: one function can be `def using_for_loop(total_points): ...`, another `def using_numpy(total_points): ...`. The first would do what you're already doing, the other could be along the lines of `numpy.vectorize` and `numpy.count_nonzero`.

Comment: @9000 thanks for the comment, could you show how this would be used in my code? really stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph not showing is mysterious, perhaps try `plt.show()`. Alternatively, you can save the plot using `savefig`. Here is a working function (just modifying your posted code in the question) for the first part of your code together with the desired output plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

def monte_carlo(n_points):
    xin, yin, xout, yout = [[] for _ in range(4)] # Defining all 4 lists together
    insidecircle = 0

    for _ in range(n_points):
        x = random()
        y = random()
        if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
            insidecircle += 1
            xin.append(x)
            yin.append(y)
        else:
            xout.append(x)
            yout.append(y)

    print ("The estimated value of Pi for N = %d is %.4f" %(n_points, 4*insidecircle/n_points))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.scatter(xin, yin, color='g', marker='o', s=4)
    ax.scatter(xout, yout, color='r', marker='o', s=4)
    plt.savefig('monte_carlo.png')

n_points = 10**4
monte_carlo(n_points)

> The estimated value of Pi for N = 10000 is 3.1380
```

[image]

**Vectorized approach** You can call it one-liner if you exclude the `print` statement in the function. I leave the time analysis as your homework

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def monte_carlo(n_points, x, y):
    pi_vec = 4*(x**2 + y**2 <= 1).sum()/n_points
    print ("The estimated value of Pi for N = %d is %.4f" %(n_points, pi_vec))

# Generate points
n_points = 10**4
x = np.random.random(n_points)
y = np.random.random(n_points)
# x = [random() for _ in range(n_points)] # alternative way to define x
# y = [random() for _ in range(n_points)] # alternative way to define y

# Call function
monte_carlo(n_points, x, y)

> The estimated value of Pi for N = 10000 is 3.1284
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of two variables `x` and `y` by just using a single array of x and y points as follows:

```
pts = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 2*n_points).reshape((n_points, 2))
monte_carlo(n_points, pts) # Function will be def monte_carlo(n_points, pts):
```

And in the function use

```
pi_vec = 4*(pts[:,0]**2 + pts[:,1]**2 <= 1).sum()/n_points
```

Comment: in the question it says write functions that accept the number of monte carlo functions as input value. Does this code do that?

Comment: to run this code do i need to ad import numpy as np? what other ones would i need to use? could you edit that in then i will run it and accept your answer!

Comment: the graph still hasnt appeared for some reason, strange

Comment: you are correct! last question. How could I add a second function that uses the vectorized form of that algorithim? it says it should only be one line

Comment: I am adding the vectorised solution now

Comment: you have been great help! thanks, now I will try and figure out how to record how fast each function was

Comment: do those two functions go in the same code? or are they seperate

Comment: You can name them differently and use different variable names as arguments

Comment: how could i put them in the same code? could you edit that, then i will be able to test the time

Comment: should the second function plot a graph as well?

Comment: For that I will have to edit my complete answer. It isn't difficult. Just try to merge the two codes. It's quite straighforward. You don't need the second function to plot the graph because both the ways are same in output but only differ in performance

Comment: okay thanks, I tried to merge them together but ran into an error. Anyways, thanks for your time!

Comment: Try to solve the error. It might just be some syntax related or missing variables or undefined variables. I added further shorter way in the vectorised approach just now. Good luck :)

Comment: in performance do you just mean speed? or accuracy of answer?

Comment: I mean speed. The answer will be closer to the value of pi depending on the number of points you sample. Just take 10**6 points for comparing speed.

Comment: last question then I have to go, that vectorized approach uses the same algorithm as the first? as mention in the question picture i have posted?

Comment: Yes, that's the same equation I have coded `x**2 + y**2 <= 1`. I multiplied by 4 and divided by N to get Pi. I too have to go now :)

Comment: You can also use pseudo-randomized **complex numbers**, and compute the mean of the points which **norm** is less or equal 1, e.g., ```4*np.mean(np.abs(np.array([1,1j]).dot(np.random.rand(2,1000)))<=1)```